Mechanical drilling and Photo lithography alignment 1st layer of PCB
I am new to the PCB manufacturing industry.

Can a Plated through hole to a Copper pad represent a 1st layer alignment post lithography?

It is very confusing to me.

How does one measure the alignment of a drilling maching and a photolithographic tool?
Since it doesnt make sense to measure a pad created by a photolithography tool to a plates through hole. (Setting the pad center as (0,0)


I’m voting to close this question because it is off topic (does not discuss a specifically electronics subject); consider a mechanical engineering or metrology Stack.
